# VHDL 2008 > generic package in an entity: error expecting BASICID or EXTENDEDID

Tags: package, vhdl, generic-list, synthesis

When trying to declare an entity with a formal generic package (`ieee.fixed_generic_pkg`):

```
library ieee;
context ieee.ieee_std_context;

entity myent is
  generic ( package myfpkg is new ieee.fixed_generic_pkg generic map (<>) );
end entity;
```

I get the following error:

`Syntax error at or near "package", expecting BASICID or EXTENDEDID`

I have also tried:

```
library ieee;
context ieee.ieee_std_context;
use ieee.fixed_generic_pkg;

entity myent is
  generic ( package myfpkg is new ieee.fixed_generic_pkg generic map (<>) );       
end entity;
```

that doesn't work neither.

However, if I declare any dummy instance of the package, it works without any error:

```
library ieee;
context ieee.ieee_std_context;
package fpkg is new ieee.fixed_generic_pkg;

--

library ieee;
context ieee.ieee_std_context;

entity myent is
  generic ( package myfpkg is new ieee.fixed_generic_pkg generic map (<>) );       
end entity;
```

What is the proper way of declaring an entity with a formal generic package, without having to previously instantiate a package of the same type?

**EDIT**

The tool I'm using is HDL Designer 2015.1b. I think that generic packages are supported. Indeed, the following example throws no error:

```
library slfnlib;
use slfnlib.gen_consts;
use slfnlib.gen_wb_ctypes;

package gen_ctypes is
  generic ( package cs is new slfnlib.gen_consts generic map (<>) );  

  package wb is new slfnlib.gen_wb_ctypes generic map (
    g_mo => cs.g_mo,
    g_bas => cs.g_bas );

end package;
```

**EDIT2**

While working with several generic packages (declarations, instantiations, use...), I realized that full projects are correctly compiled. I also got the same error several times, when analizing only parts of them.

Then, I concluded that I can not analyze any generic package/entity on its own with DesignChecker. However, there is an easy workaround, which is just to use those components as we would in any practical design. That should be done anyway, in order to either simulate and synthetize the design. The key message is not bother with what the tools provide, until the body of the code actually makes sense as a practical design.

Comment: Might be worth describing which tool/version reports this. Some tools may still not support generic packages.

Comment: I've edited the question to indicate the tool/version info. Also, I have added an example which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks to have a similar structure to the example in section 6.5.7.2 of the LRM ("Generic map aspects") except your top-level is an entity whereas in their example it is a package.

Your original code compiled fine on the two tools I tried, so it looks to me like there is an issue in whatever tool you are using. I suggest you take it up with the tool vendor.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm using HDL Designer 2015.1b. May I know which tools have you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry, you may not. You will probably find that discussing publicly what your tool can and cannot do is against the licence terms. In my job, I am very grateful to the various vendors for their support and so do take those licence terms seriously.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor while the letter of the license may say that, in practice, vendors are unlikely to have any objection to a statement that their tool does the job!

Comment: I get your point, MatthewTaylor, and I'd like you to excuse me if asking about the tools made you feel uncomfortable.
In fact, I didn't mean to discuss what tools can do, but how I should input code. Indeed, If you used any of the tools I tried, that would mean that I have some configuration problem.
Anyway, I am trying to take it up with the tool vendor (although it is not being easy).
Then, I take yours as the valid answer. Thank you both, you and @BrianDrummond, for your time.